# HTML table with the user able to dynamically change the width of the columns by dragging

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm sure it's possible but I can't figure out how and I can't remember seeing it on any website.

I'm after creating a table view where the user can hover over the edge of a column and drag to re-size that column, just like what you do in excel for example.

Are there any libraries that support that kind of feature and if I want to make it myself without any libraries, how do I re-render the table after the user has stopped dragging, or even render the table during the drag so that the column width would change while the user is dragging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

colResizable is a great plugin for what you need. using `jQuery`

Documentation: http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/euka4rm3/